# Code Coverage for WebServices Class

Tags: apex

I'm trying to put a webservices class into production but its telling me my code coverage is only 58%. I'm familiar with having to write a test class for triggers but what if this is a just a class, how do you make sure this code hits the 75%?

[image]

```
global class ClientAllocation {

WebService static List<Account> getAccount()
{
    string strQuery = 'select Name, CASESAFE_ID__c, Production_environment__c, External_Identifier__c, Member_Web_URL__c, Administration__c, Pensions__c, Broking__c, Helpdesk__c, Helpdesk_Email__c, Helpdesk_Number__c, Account_Owner_Name__c, Darwin_Support_Associate__c, Selection_Window_Open_Month__c WHERE Type = Client';
    return Database.query(strQuery);

}

}
```

Comment: The query doesn't look valid. You are better off using static SOQL for something like this i.e. `return [select Name, ...];` so the query is checked at compile time. You still need to write a test though.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with something like this:

```
@isTest
public class SampleTestClass{
    public static @isTest void sampleTestMethod(){
        list<Account> alist = ClientAllocation.getAccount();
        // system.assert();
    }
}
```

In order to actually perform a test, you would have to use the assert() method to verify that the list of accounts returned by the function is what you expected them to be. What I have above is a very basic framework. You should use it as a framework for building your test.

And, thank you Keith for pointing out that the method is static.

Comment: The method is static...

Comment: Hi Keith, could you elaborate? what do you mean by that?

Comment: Martin, how would I go about writing a test for a class? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks Martin, that seemed to have worked for that particular class. I'm now faced with another challenge where its saying my overall code coverage is less than 75%!!! There are several very old triggers and classes that i think might be causing this.

Comment: @user3480962 Writing test code can be quite a bit of extra work. Best of luck.